# show that a function has a maximum

Tags: real-analysis, limits, continuity

Here is the exercise :
Let f: R+ → R continues with f(0)=0=limx→+∞ f(x). Show that f admits a maximum on R+ = [0, +∞[.

My proof is the following :
As f(0)=0=limx→+∞ f(x): $\forall \epsilon > 0 \exists \alpha \forall x \geq \alpha : \mid f(x) \mid < \epsilon $. Then it is true for $\epsilon = M \in \mathbb{R} $ , so f is bounded on [$\alpha ; \infty$[ .
Then as f is continuous on [0;$\alpha$] it is bounded on this interval, lets say by N $\in \mathbb{R}$.
Then let X = max(M;N); then f is bounded by X on R+.
Hence f admits a supremum and because f is continuous on R+, the supremum is a maximum.

Is this reasoning correct?

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not correct. You have proved that $f$ is bounded above, but it doesn't follow from that that $f$ has a maximum. For instance, $x\mapsto-\frac1{x+1}$ is also bounded above on $\Bbb R^+$, but it has no maximum.

If you always have $f(x)\leqslant 0$, then $0$ is a maximum. Otherwise, take $x_0\in\Bbb R^+$ such that $f(x_0)>0$. There is some $\alpha>0$ such that $x\geqslant\alpha\implies f(x)<f(x_0)$. So, consider the maximum $M$ of the restriction of $f$ to $[0,\alpha]$ and then $M$ will be the maximum of $f$.

Comment: But here $ f(0)\ne 0$

Comment: @hamam_Abdallah Indeed. I was not saying that the statement is false. I was just saying that just because $f$ is bounded above, you cannot deduce that it has a maximum.

Comment: i think you have to consider the maximum on the restriction to $[0,\alpha]$.

Comment: @Alan I've edited my answer. Thank you.

Comment: Yeah I agree but in your example the limit is - $\infty$ when x --> 0 . So it is not the same. So you obtain the f(x_0) with the limits definition and this x_0 is the point where f is going to go down to 0 ?

Comment: In my example, $\lim_{x\to0}f(x)=-1$, not $-\infty$. **Of course** that  it's not the same as in your problem. It could not be since the statement that you are supposed to prove is true, and therefore there is no counter-example. All I wanted was to explain that  just because $f$ is bounded above, you cannot deduce that it has a maximum. And there isn't necessarily such a thing as “the point where $f$ is going to go down to $0$”. I took **any** $x_0$ such that $f(x_0)>0$.